# Site adds blank content outside of 100% width, how can I remove it?

Tags: css, padding

I'm working on a new site and I'm having an issue where the page is adding extra blank content to the right of the site container.

This makes the site feel akward as there is no point in scrolling right, because there's no content there...

[image: Here's a screenshot of the problem]

Appreciate any help in trying to fix it or find out what's causing it :)

Here's [a live](http://screenpartner.no/new/) version.

*EDIT*

I managed to fix the problem using overflow: hidden; on the .main-content container. I'm guessing this might cause problems in a later stage at the development, but for now it works..

Comment: I've tested your link in Firefox, you've got another problems in that browser... It looks good in Chrome though.

Comment: You're right, that does not look good :S Seems like a floating bug actually.. I might've forgot to clear it somewhere..

Comment: I noticed there is a margin right:-100%; on your flex-active-slide class, why? :P Disable it and it seemed fine

Comment: Thanks Bill, unfortunately it doesn't fix the initial problem though..

Comment: To be honest I couldnt reproduce the problem as  your image, next thing I suggest is install this plugin for mozilla: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/html-validator/, you will notice there are some stray anchor tags. Maybe something like that does the bug, let me know

Answer (score 0):

Michael--

It looks like the FlexSlider plugin you're using has an odd attribute in its stylesheet to add a 40 px right margin. To fix it, edit the following snippet in the flexslider.css file of your site, chaing the 40px value margin to 0px:

```
/** Custom Meta Slider CSS **/
.flexslider {
    background: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -o-box-shadow: none;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0 0 40px 0;
}
```

Let me know if that doesn't do the trick!

Comment: Hey, I don't think it adds any margin-right. That rule adds margin to the bottom :)

Comment: Ha, oops, it's early, I'm in need of coffee and I got my margin ordering confused. Glad you got it working, though. Overflow:hidden will get the job done, even if not the most optimal solution.

Comment: Don't worry, those numbers trip me up everytime as well ;)